# Dashboard Whitescreen of Death?

Tags: errors, dashboard

I can login into the Dashboard and see the menu of the left, it shows that there are 7 plugin updates and a WordPress update required but on the right I have a blank screen, I can see the update to WordPress button along the top but when you click on it nothing happens. I have read several posts and update the config file to true to show debug, this is the result:

---

> **Notice:** wp_enqueue_style was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles
> should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts,
> admin_enqueue_scripts, or init hooks. Please see Debugging in
> WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version
> 3.3.) in /home/breinton/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3587
>
> **Notice:** wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles
> should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts,
> admin_enqueue_scripts, or init hooks. Please see Debugging in
> WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version
> 3.3.) in /home/breinton/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3587
>
> **Notice:** register_sidebar_widget is deprecated since version 2.8! Use
> wp_register_sidebar_widget() instead. in
> /home/breinton/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3467
>
> **Notice:** register_widget_control is deprecated since version 2.8! Use
> wp_register_widget_control() instead. in
> /home/breinton/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3467

---

Any help or advice on how to fix this and update the Wordpress without loosing anything would be really appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you ain't got debugging activated. Please [enable debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) - [blueprint for `wp-config.php`](https://gist.github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/4063197) - and file an [edit] so we can look at your error messages. So far those are only deprecation notices that wouldn't cause an abort of your script.

Comment: I have renamed the plugins folder and also the themes folder but even though plugins have now disappeared the screen to the right of the dashboard menu is still blank white?? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You have active a plugin or theme, that include scripts or styles via function `wp_enqueue_style` and `wp_enqueue_script`. Since version 3.3 is it not possible to enqueue script and styles without a hook. Find the source and fix this, is easy to do that. The [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) have for this topic a fine documentation.

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

The same problem is on the your widget topic.
To find the right plugin or theme, deactivate all plugins and switch to  default theme. Switch on step by step and check.

Comment: How do i deactivate all the plugins? When I click on the left menu the right menu is blank, (white)

Comment: I have managed to download the error log as follows:                                        [03-Mar-2012 15:20:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/breinton/public_html/wp-content/plugins/timthumb-vulnerability-scanner/class-cg-tvs-plugin.php on line 115

Comment: @user44956 Just rename the plugin folder to something `plugins1` check and see.

Comment: Also try switching to the default theme by renaming your current theme's folder in wp-content/themes and adding "-old" to the end of the folder name using via FTP or SFTP or whatever file management application your host provides.

Comment: I tried renaming the folder by putting OLD on the end and website went blank??

Comment: Doing this also for the themes/your-theme folder, that plugins and theme is inactive.

Answer (score 0):

you have have answered your own question, the problem is the timthumb-vulnerability-scanner plugin, delete it or move it from your plugins folder then logout refresh browser cache and log back in.

Comment: It looks as thought the OP may have already tried this per this comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/129240/dashboard-whitescreen-of-death#comment182889_129271

Comment: that wouldn't work as plugins and themes don't rely on folder names, wordpress gets the theme name from the  style.css comment header, plugins are similar except the plugins php file has the plugin name. its best to remove completely from theme or plugin folder

Comment: If you rename the folder (or delete it) for a plugin or theme the plugin/theme will be deactivated. It has worked that way ever since I can remember, which is back to about 1.5. Renaming the folder _does_ work. Try it with an active theme and visit the Theme menu on the backend. You will see a notice about reverting to the default theme. The process used to be more seamless than that and didn't require the backend visit, if I remember correctly.